# How to center in <figure> without text-align?

Tags: html, css

I like to think I know a lot about CSS, and know how to center things.

Alas, every once in a while, I always fail to center something. I'm probably doing something stupid, and those are the times when I ask stackoverflow.

http://jsfiddle.net/Svwh3/

`margin: auto;` with widths doesn't center.

I can't use text-align, because there'll be text elements in it. Putting `text-align: left;` on them wouldn't be good for internationalization, right? Why isn't there a `text-align: root;`...

So what's a proper solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep `margin: 0 auto 0.55em;` on `figure > *` and add `display:block;`

I don't think `margin: 0 auto` works unless it's applied to block elements.

Comment: I'd add it to `figure img`, just in case.

Comment: Of course. When I put `display: block` on `figure` I had the second figure disabled, and when testing on the page I'm working on I had `img` set to `display: block;` by default, yet had only tested the figure.

Comment: @Artyom I thought that too but then realised OP mentioned there will be 'text elements in it'. I thought I'd keep my answer simple and stick to his code.

Comment: But what if I want the centered element to have an automatic width?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I don't know. It may be that you can't.

Answer (score -1):

I added this to your jsfiddle:

```
figure img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```